# Query inside while loop run only for first value

Tags: php

I am trying to use first query's fetch value as second query's where condition with help of while loop. What I want is:
Run for all possible value like A B C D E
what I get is:
Run only for first value A.
Here Is my code.

```
  <?php
        $qu="Select DISTINCT Branch from branch";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
        if($res && mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
            {
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                { 
                    $br=$row['Branch'];
                    $qu="select count(P_no) as pick from add_new_patient where Branch='$br' and Result='POSITIVE'";
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
                    if($res && mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
                        {
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                                  { 
                                    $rs=$row['pick'];
                                    echo "<tr><td>$br</td><td>$rs</td>";
                                  }
                        }   

                 }
            }
     ?>
```

Comment: Please check the posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your result set of outer loop with result set of inner loop.  You could correct your code as follow:

```
<?php
        $qu="Select DISTINCT Branch from branch";
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$qu);
        if($res && mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
            {
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                { 
                    $br=$row['Branch'];
                    $qu="select count(P_no) as pick from add_new_patient where Branch='$br' and Result='POSITIVE'";
                    $res2=mysqli_query($con,$qu); // Here you were overwriting
                    if($res2 && mysqli_num_rows($res2)>0)
                        {
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2))
                                  { 
                                    $rs=$row['pick'];
                                    echo "<tr><td>$br</td><td>$rs</td>";
                                  }
                        }   

                 }
            }
     ?>
```